# How do I get my for loop to run before it prints?

Tags: javascript, html, loops

I have this set up in html to allow a user to input a number, then click submit, and I am hoping to change how many periods will come out in the output box. Currently, just one period will print (I know this is calling to the variable declared in the conditional portion). I assume this means it is collecting the value before the loop runs, but I don't know how to fix that. Please help. (I'm happy to provide the rest of the code if needed but I'm fairly certain I have isolated the problem.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function makepyramid() {
        var numberin = document.getElementById("numberin");
        var pyramid = numberin.value;
        var mathablenumber = +numberin.replace;
        for (n = 0, spaces ="."; n < mathablenumber; n++)
            {
            var spaces = spaces +=".";
        }
        var txtOutput = document.getElementById("txtOutput");
        txtOutput.value = "Hi there, " + spaces + "!"
    } // end makepyramid
</script>
```

Comment: What is the meaning of this line? `var mathablenumber = +numberin.replace;`

Comment: `textOutput.value = 'Hi there, '+'.'.repeat(numberHere)+'!'` makes more sense than a loop in this case. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat

Comment: Another thing, have you defined any variable 'n' in a higher scope than this function? like for example global? Because the way you created the loop you did not declare 'n' inside it, so it must have been defined elsewhere

Comment: @AksJacoves That converts the html string number to what javascript recognizes as a number it can do math on. I will need to call back the original number the user input for a later portion of the code I haven't done yet.

Comment: @StackSlave this is only the first hurdle of what I am trying to accomplish, which is eventually a small pyramid type shape

Comment: No, it doesn't. `+numberin.input` converts a string to a number. `+numberin.replace` doesn't, since `numberin.replace` is not a string.

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon thank you for informing me. I am INCREDIBLY new (obviously) I have since removed it. I must have misunderstood a different post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically your problem is in the row `var mathablenumber = +numberin.replace;`. I dont know what does it do and why do you need it. If your input field is number type it already returns you the number type value and you can use it for iteration directly

I have edited your code a little:

```js
function makepyramid() {
  var numberin = document.getElementById("numberin");
  var pyramid = numberin.value;  
  
  // You can leave as one line as well 
  //for (var n = 0, spaces = '.'; n < pyramid; n++) spaces +=".";
  for (var n = 0, spaces = '.'; n < pyramid; n++) {
   spaces +=".";
  }
  
  var txtOutput = document.getElementById("txtOutput");
  txtOutput.value = "Hi there, " + spaces + "!"
} // end makepyramid

makepyramid();
```

```html
<input id="numberin" value="5" type="number" />
<input id="txtOutput" type="text"/>
```

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon Thank you, Edited.

Comment: I think what happens in the OP's code is that `+numberin.replace` returns NaN, which makes `n < mathablenumber` return false, so the loop never runs.

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon yeah makes sense, though for this purpose that line is not needed at all, so I cut it down.

Comment: I tried this but now I get no output on the page where before I at least got "hello, .!"

Comment: I got it to do what I wanted! I did want to leave in the spaces = spaces += "." I used your code but left that part in tact. Thanks so much! 
Somebody upvote this person!  (my rep is too low)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure of your goal here. Thought I'd show some technique:

```js
let doc, htm, bod, nav, M, I, mobile, S, Q, aC, rC, tC, CharPyramid; // for use on other loads
addEventListener('load', ()=>{
doc = document; htm = doc.documentElement; bod = doc.body; nav = navigator; M = tag=>doc.createElement(tag); I = id=>doc.getElementById(id);
mobile = nav.userAgent.match(/Mobi/i) ? true : false;
S = (selector, within)=>{
  var w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelector(selector);
}
Q = (selector, within)=>{
  var w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelectorAll(selector);
}
aC = function(){
  const a = [...arguments];
  a.shift().classList.add(...a);
  return aC;
}
rC = function(){
  const a = [...arguments];
  a.shift().classList.remove(...a);
  return rC;
}
tC = function(){
  const a = [...arguments];
  a.shift().classList.toggle(...a);
  return tC;
}
CharPyramid = function(char = '*'){
  this.char = char;
  this.build = height=>{
    let p = M('div');
    for(let i=1,r,c=this.char,l=height+1; i<l; i++){
      r = M('div'); p.appendChild(r);
      for(let n=0,d; n<i; n++){
        d = M('div'); d.textContent = c; r.appendChild(d);
      }
    }
    return p;
  }
}
// magic happens below
const pyr_chars = I('pyr_chars'), pyr = I('pyr'), cp = new CharPyramid('.'), pyr_er = I('pyr_er');
pyr.appendChild(cp.build(+pyr_chars.value));
pyr_chars.oninput = function(){
  let v = this.value;
  if(v.match(/^[1-9][0-9]*$/)){
    aC(this, 'yes'); pyr_er.textContent = pyr.innerHTML = ''; pyr.appendChild(cp.build(+v));
  }
  else{
    rC(this, 'yes'); pyr.innerHTML = ''; pyr_er.textContent = 'Numbers Only';
  }
}
}); //
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
btml,body{
  background:#ccc;
}
label,input,.er{
  font:bold 22px Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
label{
  color:#fff; text-shadow:-1px 0 #000,0 1px #000,1px 0 #000,0 -1px #000;
}
input{
  width:100%; color:#000; padding:3px 5px; border:1px solid #c00; border-radius:3px; margin-top:2px;
}
input.yes{
  border-color:#0c0;
}
.er{
  color:#a00; font-size:14px; text-align:center; margin-top:3px;
}
.pyr{
  margin-top:10px; text-align:center;
}
.pyr>div{
  display:inline-block; background:#fff; color:#0b0; text-align:center; 
}
.pyr>div>div>div{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<label for='pyr_chars'>Pyramid Height:</label>
<input class='yes' id='pyr_chars' type='number' value='9' min='1' />
<div class='er' id='pyr_er'></div>
<div class='pyr' id='pyr'></div>
```

Comment: Holy heck @stackslave. I am so new that much of this is above my head, but I am doing my best to work it out and I am impressed for sure. My end goal is (if input is 3)supposed to look like
__#__#
_##__##
###__###

also "_" is supposed to be a space but it's not as pretty when it's not monospace

Comment: I am realizing the shift+enter does not work in this text box. __#__# new line, _##__##__ new line, ###__###

Answer (score -1):

Well, I may not get your point exactly,
anyway if you want to make your code be waiting for the for loop you can simply make it async, try this

```
async function processArray(array) {
  array.forEach(item => {
    // define synchronous anonymous function
    // IT WILL THROW ERROR!
    await func(item);
  })
}
```

Also, you have a mistyping when you are initializing the spaces over and over again inside the loop. that will not get your work done at all.
define the `var spaces` outside the loop.

Comment: An async function is not going to fix the OP's problem.